# Limits: Can't understand this worked example

Tags: limits, factoring

I can't seem to understand the following given example while working with Limits.

$$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}({x\over1+x})^x = \lim\limits_{x\to \infty}({x +1 -1\over1+x})^x = \lim\limits_{x \to \infty}(1- {1\over1+x})^x = \lim\limits_{x \to \infty}(1+ {1\over-1-x})^{(-1-x)({x\over-1-x})} = e^{-1}$$

I understand most of it, except for this part;
$$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}({x +1 -1\over1+x})^x = \lim\limits_{x \to \infty}(1- {1\over1+x})^x$$

What happends to the x in the numerator? It seems to have been left out but I wouldn't see how this could have been done in a correct / proper way.

If anyone could give and hints or suggestions, that'd be great.

Thanks in advance,
Michiel

Comment: $x+1=1+x{}{}{}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\frac{x+1-1}{x+1}=\frac{x+1}{x+1}-\frac{1}{x+1}$

Comment: Thanks, may have seen like a dumb question (which it was) but somehow I just couldn't see it.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case....
$$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\left({x +1 -1\over1+x}\right)^x = \lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\left({x +1\over 1+x} -{1\over1+x}\right)^x = \lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\left(1- {1\over1+x}\right)^x $$